# Php eliminar ficheros que no estan en el servidor

Tags: php, comparaciones

Actualmente estoy haciendo un php que lanza una consulta, esta consulta saca el id del usuario y el id del documentos, si los juntas, obtienes el nombre de la carpeta, una vez hecho esto, otra parte del php, coge todas las carpetas que hay y las mete en otro array, una vez hecho esto, intento sacar una 3 array que obtenga las carpetas que no están en la consulta de la primera array, de momento tengo hecho todo esto, pero hay carpetas que las detecta y aun así no las borra, o hay carpetas que están en la consulta y las borra etc etc...
Dejo el php aquí.

```
<?php
include('../database/config.php');
//Consulta
    $query="SELECT id_usuario, id_documento FROM DOCUMENTOS";
//Fin de la consulta


$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); //Lanza la consulta y la almacena en una variable

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //Almacena en arrays los 

$carpeta[] = $row['id_usuario'].$row['id_documento']; //Con la combinacion de la columna id_usuario y id_documento se genera la carpeta y se almacena dentro la array

//Programa para sacar todos los directorios
$directorio = opendir(".");

while($archivo = readdir($directorio))
    {    
        if ((!is_file($archivo))and($archivo!='.')and($archivo!='..')) 
        {
            $documentos[]=$archivo;
        }
    }
closedir($directorio);  

$resultado = array_diff($documentos, $carpeta);
$numero = count($resultado);
for($i=0; $i<$numero; $i++){
    //unlink($resultado[$i]."/*");
    array_map('unlink', glob("$resultado[$i]/*"));
    rmdir($resultado[$i]);


}
print_r($resultado);
?>
```

Adjunto sql

```
CREATE TABLE `DOCUMENTOS` (
  `id_usuario` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `id_documento` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `formato` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `tiempo` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `minutos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

**EDIT 1**

Falta primero de todo hacer un while para que las variables se introduzcan dentro de la array creada, ahora el problema lo da el unlink, dejo la primera modificacion:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $carpeta[] = $row['id_usuario'].$row['id_documento']; //Con la combinacion de la columna id_usuario y id_documento se genera la carpeta y se almacena dentro la array
}
```

**2 Edit**

Acabo de modificar el while un poco, primero hacer un array map y después hacer el count de los directorios totales, al hacer un count de la diferencia, este podría tener un 2 valores, pero almacenados en la posición 1 y pongamos que otro al 200, de esta manera, nunca llegaba a la posición 200, pego los cambios y soluciono ya post.

```
$resultado = array_diff($documentos, $carpeta);
$numero = count($documentos);
for($i=0; $i<$numero; $i++){
    //unlink($resultado[$i]."/*");
    array_map('unlink', glob("$resultado[$i]/*"));
    rmdir($resultado[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Amigo esto es una pesadilla de seguridad. 
Imagine que cada sitio web podría eliminar todos los archivos en su computadora local. `PHP` se ejecuta en el servidor y el archivo es local. Cuando carga un archivo a un sitio web, `PHP` puede procesar ese archivo porque el navegador envía el archivo al servidor que ejecuta el servidor web con `PHP`

Comment: **No puedes**, `PHP` se ejecuta en el servidor, no puede hacer nada en la máquina del cliente. Y `Javascript` no puede eliminar archivos, esto es una pesadilla de seguridad si fuera posible.

Comment: En teoria solo elimina duplicados del servidor, no se ejecuta en cliente

Comment: Lo que quieres es desenlazar un archivo que este en una carpeta?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Primero eliminar el archivo, después la carpeta

Comment: Qué tipo de información tiene el archivo? No podrías hacer que se guarde en la DB y después mediante una query eliminás la columna con dicha información? En vez de estar tocando archivos locales.

Comment: @Kleith El php solo saca el nombre de las carpetas, despues, estas pueden contener diferentes tipos de archivos

Comment: Esto: `array_map('unlink', glob("$resultado[$i]/*"));` realmente no eliminará la carpetas, puede que le muestre alguna advertencia de error.

Comment: Tengo entendido que si la carpeta tiene archivos dentro PHP no la elimina, lo ideal es determinar si dichas carpetas tienen ficheros antes de intentar eliminarlas del servidor

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que pude entender de su pregunta me baso en el comentario que realizó: [Primero eliminar el archivo, después la carpeta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164627/php-eliminar-ficheros-que-no-estan-en-el-servidor?noredirect=1#comment309567_164627), con este ejemplo puedes desvincular todos los archivos dentro de un directorio y luego eliminar ese directorio.

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) para buscar todos los archivos que coincidan con un patrón.

```
function recursiveRemoveDirectory($directorio)
{
    foreach(glob("{$directorio}/*") as $file)
    {
        if(is_dir($file)) { 
            recursiveRemoveDirectory($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($directorio);
}
```

> Documentación:
>
> - [unlink](http://php.net/unlink)
> - [rmdir](http://php.net/rmdir)